# Javascript graph with quadratic-based gradient across background

Tags: javascript, d3.js, gradient

I am trying to create a graph using Javascript in which the background has a gradient that changes colors across a few quadratic lines.  I have three distinctly colored lines based on y=ax^2 + bx+ c, and I want the background of the graph to be a gradient between them, like the image below.  I have been trying to do this with D3, but am open to any other free libraries out there.

[image: An example of what I'm trying to do]

Comment: have you looked at any d3 examples - http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1086421?

Comment: Yes, I have.  But I've really only been able to find basic linear and radial gradients, which is not exactly the case in this example.  I think there might be a way to use radial gradients to solve this problem, but if so, it would take some extra manipulation that I'm not sure about.